# Old SORA compatibility with new Claris

Tags: shimano, compatibility, groupsets

I want to 2x check within the community if I got it right the compatibility question between Shimano components.

I have an old (~2006) `Sora` groupset on my bike (2x8 speed). I upgraded last year to `Claris ST-2400` brake lever set (it is for 3x8 but with proper tuning can be used with 2x8).

Now I have to change my crankset `Sora FC-3301 175mm/52x39`. I'm not 100% sure, but the `Claris FC-2450` seems to be compatible.

- both `FC-3301` and `FC-2450` are for 2x8 derailleur (what I have);
- both use Octalink axle profile, the `FC-2450` needs `Octalink V2` but for the old `FC-3301` couldn't find what Octalink version is compatible with. However, for both the `BB-ES25` bottom bracket is recommended (what I have currently). So I suppose `V2` is ok;
- both have 175mm arm length versions.

Did I miss something?
Is `FC-2450`a compatible replacement for the `FC-3301`?

If I understand well, the higher class Shimano groupset technologies are propagated to the lower class group set while time passes, so like in my case the old Sora set now is compatible with the Claris set, but not compatible with the new Sora set, right?

**UPDATE**

A cheaper solution would be if I change only the chainrings. 
But I have no idea if a **2x10** ring set with the same number of teeth (52 and 39) and the same bolt circle (130mm) is compatible with my old chainrings for a **2x8**.
for example: `Shimano Ultegra 6700 Road Chainring 2x10-speed`

- I aks the only support at bike-components and they think is ok the FC6700 chain ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these should be compatible.

Sheldon Brown's glossary indicates that the FC-3301 used Octalink V2 (see this reference page: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_n-o.html#octalink).